# Creating SharePoint 2010 Workflows in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

We have developed workflows (2013) with Visual Studio 2013 for SharePoint 2013 for a long time.

Now a customer doesn't have the infrastructure for SharePoint 2013 workflows (no wf-Manager installed), so we must create the 2010 one instead.

Is it possible to create 2010 Workflows in Visual Studio 2013? Or is it possible to run Workflows creates in VS 2013 in a compatibilty mode or similar?

Comment: Yeah this is absolutely no problem. They'll run in SP2010 mode.
You cannot run SP2013 in compatibility mode, you need to create a SP2010 workflow (with a different designer and such).

Comment: so that means, that I can creata a workflows in vs2013 with the normal workflows designer within visual studio. then I deploy it and sharepoint run this in a compatibility mode? Exists there any restrictions by using it? Because in WF's for 2013 are more possibilities as in 2010 wf's ?

Comment: No, as I said, it's not a compatibility mode. There are two types of workflows you can create in Visual Studio: The old 2010 workflows, and the new 2013 workflows. SharePoint 2013 is backwards compatible, so it allows to run the old-style 2010 workflows. You don't have the new designer. You don't have the new features. All like it was in 2010. Hope this makes more sense.